# Constant ISR shrinking and expanding

Tags: apache-kafka, broker

we have a Apache Kafka cluster with 5 brokers and 3 zookeepers.
Zokeeper is version 3.14.3 and the brokers are 2.0.0.
I've been trying for a long time now to understand why do the brokers get disconnected from the cluster - I'm getting dozens of "shrinking ISR from x,y to x" and a few seconds after fozens of "expanding ISR from x to x,y" for each partition of every topic. 
For example,

```
Nov 17 10:06:06 HOSTNAME kafka-server-start.sh[17252]: [2019-11-17 10:06:06,188] INFO [Partition topicname-14 broker=1] Expanding ISR from 1 to 1,3 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

The "expand" logs arrive ~7 seconds after the "shrink" logs, and **this repeats itself every 1-5 minutes**.

06:54:27 - Shrinking >

06:54:32 - Expanding

06:55:47 - Shrinking >

06:55:52 - Expanding

06:57:07 - Shrinking >

06:57:13 - Expanding

07:01:27 - Shrinking >

07:01:36 - Expanding

I didn't find anything that seems out of the ordinary on the zookeepers side, and nothing sticks out on the other logs files (controller.log, state-change.log, kafka-authorizer) while these show up on the server.log file.

The load is pretty balanced between the brokers, we recently added 2 more brokers but the problem is from before the addition. No broker seems too strained or anything, and they're all aligned configuration-wise.

This is the broker's server.properties:

```
ssl.key.password=XXXX
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
ssl.keystore.password=XXXX
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://HOSTNAME.FQDN:9092
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.filename=kafka.keystore.jks
zookeeper.connect=A:2181, B:2181, C:2181
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
super.users=User:admin
ssl.truststore.credentials=keystore_creds
jmx.port=9999
ssl.keystore.credentials=keystore_creds
log.roll.hours=24
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
delete.topic.enable=TRUE
message.max.bytes=2097152
ssl.truststore.password=XXXX
broker.id=1
ssl.key.credentials=keystore_creds
log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka/data
ssl.truststore.filename=kafka.truststore.jks
listeners=SASL_SSL://IPADDRESS:9092
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
log.retention.ms=86400000
log.retention.bytes=536870912000
auto.create.topics.enable=false
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=10000
num.partitions=18
default.replication.factor=2
```

Data does go successfully in and out the cluster, my problem is that producers are disconnected from my servers each time that happens and the shrinking & expansion of the partitions must cost a lot to the system and it causes producers' queue to grow until their local queue gets full.
The producers are configured to connect to a VIP, not to an array of servers or specific servers.

Let me know if there's any other info I can provide to help research the cause of the issue,
Thanks

Comment: Can  you  try to increase the value of ` zookeeper.session.timeout.ms
`

Comment: I tried to raise is from the default 6000 ms to 10,000 ms. Didn't help. Can you explain why? Or what is the logic behind the optimal setting from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading this - https://www.confluent.io/blog/hands-free-kafka-replication-a-lesson-in-operational-simplicity/ - I've increased the replica.lag.time.max.ms to 20,000 (from the default 10,000), and now the ISR expansion and shrinkage stopped

Answer (score 1):

There are many factor involved try to increase below parameters

1. replica.lag.time.max.ms
   If a follower hasn't sent any fetch requests or hasn't consumed up to the leaders log end offset for at least this time, the leader will remove the follower from isr
2. zookeeper.session.timeout.ms
   If the consumer fails to heartbeat to ZooKeeper for this period of time it is considered dead and a rebalance will occur.
3. Reduced topic replication factor in case high replication factor cater more time to ISR